# How to fire TextChanged event without using AutoPostBack property

Tags: asp.net

I have one master page and one web form selected with that master page.

In this web form I take two text boxes and one label.

Code I wrote in `C#` file [aspx.cs] as follows :

```
    protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Label1.Text = "Welcome " + TextBox1.Text;
    }
```

I don't want to keep `AutoPostBack` propery because when I press tab button then its value fires and appears to the label so that I don't want `AutoPostBack` property.

From internet i see the code for updatepanel and scriptmanager.
In updatepanel i write trigger tag but also it is not working.

my ASPX file :

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" ontextchanged="TextBox2_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TextBox1" EventName ="TextChanged" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

so how to fire `TextChanged` event.

Comment: If you don't want a postback event then your only option is to talk to the server via AJAX.

Comment: So the user changes something but you don't want the `TextChanged` event to be triggered? Isn't that confusing? However, if you don't want to postback immediately remove the `AutoPostBack=true`. The event will be triggered on the next postback anyway.

Comment: I edit my question and put in that scriptmanager and updatepanel. However still it is not work.

Comment: keeping an `UpdatePanel` doesn't mean you suppress `AutoPostBack`